# I get frustrated when I have to produce suboptimal work

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

The following situation is probably familiar for many working people:

> - **Boss**: "We're gonna do this project like A, B, E, D"
> - **Everyone**: (stumped) "Uh, what about C? Why is E before D? That's not how the alphabet works?"
> - **Boss**: (realizing he might have made a mistake) "Well, yeah, we don't have the {time/resources} to look back on earlier made decisions, we have to move forward, so stop discussing and carry on!"
> - **Everyone**: "ugh..."

In my beginning years, when this situation happened I fought for the correct thing and demanded (with varying success) to do the project the correct "A B C D" way. My colleagues however seemed to be able to deal with this perrfectly fine. They seemed to have way less frustrations and can always bring up a high amount of relativism. After some introspection I figured out the real problem is not (or at least only partially) my boss. The real problem is me **not being able to do my job when I feel there are better ways to do it**, even though that's what I'm being paid for. My boss seems more happy with a dumb slave than with a critical subordinate. I have my reasons to not back down however:

- I'm a perfectionist, I dislike chaotic/not-well-thought-out plannings
- I love my job (despite the situation), and I get a kick whenever I deliver quality. I get demotivated when I have to deliberately introduce flaws into our products.
- I'm critical: I don't want to dance like a mindless puppet to my boss's whims.
- I want the company, and myself, to grow. Crappy products feels like going in the opposite direction.
- Crappy products ALWAYS bite you in the ass at a later time - or at least our customer departments.

Apart from the not so realistically "Just quit and change jobs!", what advice could you give me to deal with this situation? I feel like I know myself, my company and my boss, and I feel like its impossible to really change either fundamentally. But maybe I can start looking at things differently.

EDIT: I'm a bit disgusted by some of the answers this question has received. This question is NOT about "Help, I'm a perfectionist and I want everything to be perfect and now I'm missing deadlines and not doing my job properly, please give me a reality check."

I work hard and deliver quality work on time. What's REALLY going on here is my boss asking me to do things in a way that's unbelievably akward, and I constantly have to either correct him, or suck it up and leave flaws in the system. What I consider flaws, many of our non-so-perfectionist employees consider to be flaws too. Thus, it is not me just me who recognizes the flaws. The difference is: they can suck it up and be cool and calm. When I suck it up I get frustrated and demotivated. How can a person try to improve that? The answer is definitely not "changing jobs".

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: You call yourself a perfectionist, but consider quiting and finding another job as unrealistic? How convenient.

Comment: @JeffO Could you enlighten your comment a bit more? Why would I be more at place at another job? I think I'll face the same problem everywhere. It's not convenient at all.

Comment: @JeffO but the risk is out of the frying pan into the fire, as most jobs are just like this and there's no way to know until your first day (or later).

Comment: I also have to ask **why** is the answer "definitely not 'changing jobs'." Are you likely to have to deal with similar challenges at many other jobs? Sure. But if you honestly believe that your boss is terrible, your company doesn't care, and that fundamentally changing them is impossible.. why **not** look for something better. Some people are actually happy in their jobs, you know, and some of those happy people are perfectionists too.

Comment: I was a perfectionist too until I realized I was the only unhappy person in the office.  Let it go.

Answer (score 8):

> The real problem is me not being able to do my job in a crappy way, even though that's what I'm being paid for.

You're not being paid to do a crappy job, ever.

You're being paid to do the best job you can, though you need to realize that in business, often the "best" product is the "first" product (or even the "on time" product).

Assuming you're on the technical side of the fence, it is *absolutely* your job to argue for technical-best against business-best, since they both do matter - and especially if your boss can't argue the technical side.

By approaching these time requirements similar to other technical quality requirements you need to achieve, you can see them in a more positive light. And by approaching your boss in a "let's work together to best meet *all* of our requirements" rather than "why are you not doing it right?" will allow for better communication and (ideally) actually producing better results.

And finally, one more thing to consider: Being able to convince other people to do the technically important things is often just as important in getting the technically important things *done* as being technically skilled enough to implement them. While your boss may just be a demanding jackass who won't listen, not all are. Spending some time to improve your soft skills in convincing/coercing/leading people will help you achieve your goals.

Answer (score 6):

There's a time for perfectionism and there's a time for doing what you're told.

You have a boss, part of that person's responsibility is to direct you in your duties.  One of the aspects of this is the schedule.  You can certainly continue doing the responsible thing by bringing up things you believe need to addressed.  Your boss will certainly continue to either use those suggestions or throw them out according to his/her interpretation of the needs of the business.

However, if you want to have a productive relationship then you need to realize your position in the bigger picture.  Do the best job you can with within the bounds that have been dictated.  If this feels like a problem then you should work towards leveling up to be in the Boss position so you can impose your will upon your own minions.

One thing to remember "iterate fast, iterate often" is a very common phrase in the development world.  It recognizes that nothing will ever be perfect but if you can get it "good enough" then you just might have a winner.  It also highlights that you *may* have the opportunity to come back and fix those other things that need to be done.  Or, if not, then you probably didn't need to spend time on those things anyway.

This is at the heart of Agile programming and a radical departure from other methodologies, such as Waterfall, which strove to architect the Perfect System(tm) and have been proven to be utter failures.

The last thing I'll leave you with is "Perfection is in the eye of the beholder."  What you consider to be a perfectly constructed class hierarchy another might consider to be an overwhelming morass of ineffectiveness.

Comment: Great first sentence. I would also say you have to know the difference between making suggestions and having the responsibility of making decisions.

Comment: Although your first sentence states there being a time for both, the rest of your answer seems to implies there is no time for perfectionism at all. Please address this.

Comment: @ChrisLively What part of my question deals with coding or software? What part makes you assume we can't deal with changing requirements? I appreciate your input but it feels like it is the answer to another question.

Comment: @user1884155: You mentioned "leave flaws in the system".  Between that and other phrasings I took it to mean that you were a programmer.  So I attempted to answer within the same language.

Comment: @user1884155: The part you should understand is simply that with any endeavor there are as many different opinions on how to accomplish the goal as their are people in the world... maybe more so.  Further, "perfect" is very context specific and often only seen by the one person calling it so.  Within a business environment, nothing is ever perfect - usually we are just striving for good enough as there are an incredible number of trade offs for every decision.  Your way might be better from one perspective but worse from another.

Comment: You mention that you want the company to grow.  This implies that it is a small operation.  Small businesses are under an incredible amount of financial pressure and often need to change on a dime to keep going.  This might mean delivering a less than optimal product just so that they can get paid and keep going.  My point is, you need to look at this from your bosses perspective.  Although that might not be possible as they are unlikely to share some critical details which would shed light on the subject.

Comment: So change the things you can and learn to live with the things that are beyond your control.

Comment: @ChrisLively I think that sums it up: "learn to live with it". I guess I will not find an answer on how to do that on this site. Thank you for giving me the perspective to fully understand what I will be dealing it.

Answer (score 4):

Let me say to start out I have every sympathy for your position. Unlike the other people who have answered, my experience is that being asked to do something in a way that's contrary to the "right" way takes way more time, as you have to increasingly contort yourself to work around problems that you have expressly been denied permission to fix.

## Everyone is entitled to their own opinion

One thing you need to realize is that in America today (let's assume that is where you are), the presumption is that all opinions are equally valid, even though you and I both know that acting on some opinions produces good results and acting on other opinions produces poor results. Unfortunately, not everyone has enough knowledge to know the difference. Maintain enough humility to realize that at least some of the time that person may be you. Sometimes you need to reserved judgment and suck it up, just in case.

Even if it's not you, sometimes it's more valuable to have everyone pull together 
In the wrong direction than to have one person pulling in the right direction, against everyone else. Sometimes you can even buy enough goodwill by at least trying an approach you consider completely stupid that maybe you can get someone to listen. And occasionally the completely stupid way works better than what you were going to try or at least well enough for now.

## Be careful how you express yours

I have a tendency to express things in ways that strongly implies "if you hadn't been so stupid, we wouldn't be having this problem." When that's what you actually think, it's kind of a hard implication to avoid.

So, when writing an email, deliberately avoid thinking of the situation that way. Write the email, then find as many different other perspectives as you can think of on the situation as you can, then reread the email and rephrase everything that comes anywhere close to accusing someone else for causing the situation. If necessary, step away again and repeat before sending.

You'll catch more flies with honey than vinegar, so think of this as a better way of getting what you want.

## Anger management

When you feel your blood boiling, it can really be hard to ratchet back on the incendiary language. So find something to do that talks you down.

In my case, it's Karate. For one thing, now I spend so much time on Karate a lot less of who I am is defined by my job. It also helps that it is highly physical/tiring and that there is no hiding who is good and knows what they are doing and who is not.

There are several forms that are very similar to counting to ten with movements you have to concentrate on. I find that if I work on a few forms, I am seldom angry afterward, so it's easier to find neutral words for things.

## If all else fails

If, after you've done all this, you still have a problem, start thinking in terms of getting the team to the absolute best place that you can for after you leave. You don't have to be in a hurry to leave, but just the mental attitude that you are preparing to leave does help with the stress.

Comment: This is gold: "sometimes it's more valuable to have everyone pull together In the wrong direction than to have one person pulling in the right direction." It really helped me to realize why others can stay calm, they must have already realized this.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

> The real problem is me not being able to do my job in a crappy way, even though that's what I'm being paid for

I'm not going to suggest a change of job, as the thing here is your feelings, not the current position.

You need to reconcile yourself that you work for a business, there is always a compromise between quality and time.

To be honest, in my experience, perfectionism is usually the worst thing, I've worked with people who have re-started approaches to a task (sometimes multiple times), striving for the perfect solution.  The result is even more botched, as they never really understood what was really wanted, so it usually gets to the point where someone else has to step in to hack a solution in order to get something out the door on time (so even more compromised).

In software development, Agile is a big thing now.  It's based on an iterative model:

- Do just enough to cover what you need to do for this iteration
- Get feedback
- Refine it next time round

(over simplification)

This actually gets to a more perfect solution as the refining helps the requester fine tune what they actually want, so we get closer to the target than trying to hit it perfectly first time.

My advice, probably worth spending some time on the other side, either in the management of the project, or the business, to see the factors that are driving the compromises.

I always felt I became a better software architect when I also had to become a development manager, I had to learn to balance the ideals with the business's real world needs.

Answer (score 2):

It is your responsibility to speak up when something is wrong. Just "following directions" without questions is for office sycophants and the military. At the same time, you have to be willing to choose your battles here. Speaking out about every little thing or complaining about strategies that can't be reversed will erode your reputation irreversibly.

When you do speak out, the problem is that your boss might not be ready or even capable of accepting what you say. Or, even worse, *you* might be wrong instead.

If you think about it long enough, it all comes down to a matter of trust. The trust goes both ways. You need to be able to trust your boss to feel that doing what he tells you to do is not going to ruin the company and your career. He needs to feel that your criticisms and suggestions are well-founded and pragmatic.

The only way you can get to that point is to build a level of trust. Since you are the subordinate, you basically have the short end of the stick at the beginning.

You have to do what he says and build up a history of "getting along". If a project doesn't work out, don't complain, instead just suggest practical solutions to the problem in a positive professional way that doesn't cause him to lose face.

If you handled it right, the next time you have a project with this boss your suggestions will carry more weight because your boss will trust you more.

Comment: I think the "trust relationship" is a perspective to this problem I didn't realize before. Great insight! Of course, it is easier said than done, but you provide some practical points I can try to tackle.